# Haskell function non-exaustive patters in function error

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make a function that finds the local Maximum number in a list.

```
localMaxima :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
localMaxima [] = []
localMaxima [x] = []
localMaxima (e1:e2:e3:xs)
    |    (e2 > e3) && (e2 > e1) = e2 : (localMaxima (e2:(e3:xs)))
    |    otherwise = (localMaxima (e2:(e3:xs)))
```

After inputting a list of [2,3,4,1,5], the console outputs:

Non-exhaustive patterns in function localMaxima

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: What do you want `localMaxima [1,2]` to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

As you can tell from the error, your pattern matching does not cover all the cases: what happens if you give it a list with 2 elements? `e1:e2:[]` does not match any of your cases, resulting in a non-exhaustive patterns error.

## Solution

The solution is fairly easy: add a base-case for a list with two elements only. Assuming a point on the boundary cannot be a local min/max, your function should look something like this.

```
localMaxima :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
localMaxima [] = []
localMaxima [x] = []
localMaxima [a,b] = []
localMaxima (e1:e2:e3:xs)
    |    (e2 > e3) && (e2 > e1) = e2 : (localMaxima (e2:(e3:xs)))
    |    otherwise = (localMaxima (e2:(e3:xs)))
```

Furthermore, you can simplify this even more by

- noting `:` is right-associative
- use pattern wildcard `_`
- make your type signature more generic

You can now have

```
localMaxima :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
localMaxima (e1:e2:e3:xs)
    |    (e2 > e3) && (e2 > e1) = e2 : localMaxima (e2:e3:xs)
    |    otherwise = localMaxima (e2:e3:xs)
localMaxima _ = []
```